# Adding HREFs to document's contents whenever regex appears in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to find every occurrence of "needle/variable" in the document's contents and replace it with "<a href="blahblah.com/needle/variable/">needle/variable</a>".

I'm trying to use:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(needle\/(variable))/g, '<a href="http://www.blahblah.com/' + $2 + '"> '+$2+' </a>');
```

but for some reason it's not capturing the $1 and $2. Also, is there a better way to be doing this? The content "needle/variable" that I'm looking at is not guaranteed to be anywhere specific, it could be anywhere in the document.

Comment: Note: If you don't need to create a reference to a group, use `(?:` (group-me-but-dont-reference-me) instead of `(`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RegExp in Javascript doesn't map `$1`, `$2`, etc to actual variables named `$1` or `$2`. Instead, you need to put those in quotes:

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(needle\/(variable))/g, '<a href="http://www.blahblah.com/$2">$2</a>');
```